# ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, libc, strcpy

I'm trying to debug a program with `gdb` and when I set a breakpoint and continue on the `strcpy()` function. I get the following response:

```
frinto@kali:~/Documents/theclang/programs/helloworld$ gcc -fno-builtin -m32 -g -o char_array char_array.c 
frinto@kali:~/Documents/theclang/programs/helloworld$ ls
a.out  char_array  char_array.c  firstprog.c  helloworld.c
frinto@kali:~/Documents/theclang/programs/helloworld$ ./char_array 
Hello, world!
frinto@kali:~/Documents/theclang/programs/helloworld$ gdb -q char_array
Reading symbols from char_array...done.
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include <string.h>
3   
4       int main() {
5           char str_a[20];
6   
7           strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
8           printf(str_a);
9       }
(gdb) break 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x11c6: file char_array.c, line 6.
(gdb) break strcpy
Breakpoint 2 at 0x1040
(gdb) break 8
Breakpoint 3 at 0x11dc: file char_array.c, line 8.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/frinto/Documents/theclang/programs/helloworld/char_array 

Breakpoint 1, main () at char_array.c:7
7           strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, strcpy_ifunc () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy.c:29
29  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

I'm on Kali 2.0 and I've installed:
`libc6-dbg` and `libc6-dbg:i386`

If it isn't obvious already, I want to get rid of this error message:

```
../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy.c: No such file or directory
```

*Thanks in advance for any help!*

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get rid of this error message:

This isn't an error. GDB is telling you that you've stopped in `strcpy_ifunc` function (see [this description](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=167) of what `IFUNC`s are), which is defined in `../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy.c` source file, and that GDB doesn't know how to find that file on the filesystem (and thus can't show you the source of `strcpy_ifunc`).

The best way to fix this is to tell GDB where to find this source. See `(gdb) help directory`.

Of course for this to work, you actually need the GLIBC sources. I don't know whether `Kali` packages sources into `libc6-dbg:i386` or not, you may have to install a separate `glibc-source` package.